# Unable to Access Custom Property in Fastify Request Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I'm facing an issue with Fastify where I'm unable to access a custom property I've set in the request object. Here's a minimal example of my Fastify server setup:

```
const app = Fastify();

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.test = "test2"; // Set test property
  next();
});

// Other middleware and registrations...

app.register(mercurius, {
  // Mercurius options...
  context: (req, res) => buildContext({
    res,
    req,
    dataSources: req.dataSources,
  }),
  // Other options...
});
```

I've set req.test to "test2" in my middleware, but when I try to access it inside my buildContext function, it's undefined:

```
export default async ({ res, req, dataSources }) => {
  console.log(req.test); // This logs undefined
}
```

I expect req.test to have the value "test2" when accessed within buildContext, but it's not working as expected. Can someone help me understand why this property is undefined in my context function?

**Additional Information:**

I'm using Fastify with Middie.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

When I log the req object instead of req.test, I see that test property is present inside the req object, but it's not in the root of the object but it's inside of something from fastify that I don't understand and that I don't know how to access:

```
[Symbol(fastify.RequestPayloadStream)]: IncomingMessage {
```

Comment: Try `req.raw.test`. Middie is an express-like stuff so the req/res object there are the underling node.js objects. Fastify uses a req/reply approach to avoid to edit those the raw node.js objects